# Constructing Autocomplete Based on A History of Past Searched Terms

Tags: iphone, ios, search

So I am working on an iOS search where I have to implement a keyword search. I have used a custom view controller with a Search Display Controller object embedded into it. What I want to do is be able to store the search terms somewhere when the search button is clicked. I have thought of two ways:

1. store them locally in the device and query them up whenever a search is performed
2. store them in the web app this iOS app is connected to and perform a GET request to the web app whenever a search is performed

The second one I know how to do but I have no idea how to do the first one.

SO how do I store the search terms locally? Also, what would be a better option? The first, the second, or another?

**EDIT**: A remote API holds the data I am querying. I want to mimic the google search app functionality, in which it stores maybe 10-20 keywords that are searched by the user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to recommend with more understanding of the data and usage.  For example, number of keywords?  keyword list static or grows?  keywords shared?  what are you searching - local or remote?

EDIT:  You clarified 10 - 20 strings.  In that case, consider something as simple as -[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:] and just persist in a file.  If you read and write in NSArray, you can work on them very quickly in memory.

Original:

If you store locally and it's a growing dynamic set of keywords, I would recommend CoreData or Sqlite directly.  Sqlite is a very fast efficient local DB.  If you do sqlite, checkout fmdb on github.  It's an objective-c wrapper.

Concerning the pros and cons:

1. Local storage will be faster - you won't have network latency.  Especially if you want to do type ahead queries on key stroke.  Keeping in memory is even faster.
2. Consider how much data you're storing.  How many key words are there?  Is it feasible to store on the device in a DB or a file?
3. Do you want the keywords to be shared from multiple users?  In that case either storing on the server or a combination of storing on the server and syncing to the device is needed.
4. Do the keywords grow over time based on usage?  In that case a local database is better.

Comment: an edit has been provided to clarify most of your concerns. I'll apply edits if ever I have missed some

Comment: what are your thoughts about using NSUserDefaults for this?

Comment: Saving as an array in NSUserDefaults or as array to file in documents will work ...